# Best practice to display the PDF file in the browser?

Tags: vb.net

Am currently working on a web application which receives the encoded text from the web service and am decoding & saving as a PDF file. Once the user clicks for the details then I am supposed to display the PDF file in the web browser.

What is the best practice to display the PDF file in the browser? Am using VB.Net 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the link to point to your pdf file. And if the user has any PDF reader installed, it will be opened using that reader.

```
<a href="yourPdfFile.pdf">The name you Want to Show as Link</a>
```

**EDIT:**
The other way, if you dont want to display as link and directly open the file, is to set the correct MIME type in the headers, so that the browsers can detect it as PDF file instead of HTML file.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","inline;filename=YourPdfFileName.pdf")
Response.End
```